# append to end of visible line with wrapped vim

Tags: vim

I've got a file with some rather long lines, which is a pain.

I'm using `:set wrap` and `:set linebreak`, which is nice, and I've rebound a few keys from [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_cursor_by_display_lines_when_wrapping) so that I can move up and down a visible line (rather than a physical line which has now been wrapped over 10-12 visible lines).

I use `A` quite a bit (append at the end of the line), but this appends at the end of the physical line, not the visible - is there a keymapping (or alternative keystroke) I can use to append to the end of the visibly wrapped line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try with `g$a`. `g$`puts you on the end of the current 'screen line' and `a` will leave you on insert mode.

Maybe a mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>a g$a
```

Answer (score 3):

`g$a` - Go to the last character of the screen line, then append.

Want a mapping?

```
:nnoremap gA g$a
```

Answer (score 1):

Type `g$` to go to the end of visible line and `a` to enter *insert* mode. I guess you could create a custom mapping for that.